# How to Prevent Spam Post/Articles in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a blog in my website using wordpress and noticed that there are spam posts such as  bride, dating and other ads that are not related to my website. I don't know where it come from as I only have an access on the dashboard. I already installed wordfence and no detected issues on the site. All of the plugins are updated and have the latest version of Wordpress.

Sometimes it published multiple articles on one day and noticed that it post at least one article everyday.

Is it happening on most of the Wordpress websites right now? How I can prevent this?

Hopefully, someone can help solve this problem. Any idea or hint to solve it will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s not about programming

Comment: Perhaps post to wordpress.stackexchange.com? Unfortunately it's off-topic here: there's no programming question, and it's very specific to WordPress. Also, this could be seen as a tool/service recommendation question (e.g. WP plugin), and that's off-topic as well.

Answer (score -2):

Go to your database then check the wp_users table and see if there are accounts that are not supposed to be there.

Comment: No other users in the database as well.